# What is the best data structure for embedded docs MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb

Suppose each of my users can save many "smart searches":

```
user = {
    'username':'johncit',
    'smart_searches': [
        {'name':'last 24 hrs','terms':{'modifiedby':datetime(2012,1,1),'title':'foobar'}},
        {'name':'blabla','terms':{'title':'whatever','otherfield':500}}
            ]
        }
```

Now say John hits his 'blabla' search.  How do I get the terms?  I can get all John's smart searches like this:

```
db.Users.find_one({
        'username':'johncit','smart_searches':{'$elemMatch':{'Name':'blabla'}}})
```

But this returns the whole document, not just the terms for the 'blabla' search, which is what I really need.  Do I then have to figure out the precise terms on the client-side?  Or is this a case for putting 'smart_searches' in their own collection?  Is there a better structure?

I would love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator) will do the trick

```
> db.Users.find({'username':'johncit','smart_searches':{'$elemMatch':{'name':'blabla'}}},{'smart_searches.$.terms':1}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5099ab303d550a068f16d5c5"),
    "smart_searches" : [
        {
            "name" : "blabla",
            "terms" : {
                "title" : "whatever",
                "otherfield" : 500
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Update:**

To update the terms with the positional operator, you can write

```
db.Users.update({'username':'johncit',
                 'smart_searches':{'$elemMatch':{'name':'blabla'}}},
                  {$set:{'smart_searches.$.terms':{title:'changed',otherfield:200}}},
                  false,true)
```

Comment: Thank you @RameshVel.  Also, where did you get the `pretty()` method?

Comment: glad it helped. `pretty()` is a helper method in mongo shell

Comment: it seems impossible however to modify the 'terms' of 'blabla' in place.  Is there some update trickery similar to the precision of the positional operator?

Comment: @MFB, updating using positional operator is just similar as the find. check my updated answer for the complete query

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator instead of the query operator.

```
db.Users.find_one(
    {'username':'johncit', 'smart_searches.name':'blabla'},
    {'username': 1, 'smart_searches': {'$elemMatch': {'name':'blabla'}}})
```

You don't need to use `$elemMatch` in your query object because you're only matching one component: `name`.